# php pass id or pass object to a function for better memory usage

Tags: php, mysql

I have call a function to get the object from MySQL like this..

```
$product_id = 8;
$product = get_Product($product_id);
```

then do something with the $product

but now, I want to do this...

```
print_product_spec($product_id)
print_product_images($product_id)
```

is it better to pass the product_id to the function and connect to database again?
or is it better to just put the object in the parameter and use the object from parameter like this..

```
//$product = an object
print_product_spec($product)
print_product_images($product)
```

Comment: I would say, it is a matter of style and convenience.

Comment: servers nowadays have lots off memory.. a database connect and a select is much slower then reusing the same object

Answer (score 1):

It's **way** faster to pass the object to the function rather than executing another DB query.
The object will be passed by reference to the function so it won't take more memory nor CPU.

Comment: "The object will be passed by reference to the function" only if you use the & operator  http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @RaymondNijland this is not correct. Objects are for all practical purposes passed by reference (or by [reference to] object identifiers to be correct). http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: "One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true" qoute is also in the documentation.

Comment: The point is, the object itself is not copied. Only its identifier is. So you'll have 2 identifiers pointing to the same object.